# Custom Asynchronous Pluggable Protocols opening app multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, protocols, pluggable

I am using Async Pluggable Protocols in order to pass data from web application (internal intranet application)to my windows application. For that, I made sure that the web application team wrote links with the protocols I have registered.

[Thread](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/platform-apis/aa767916(v%3Dvs.85)) worked for me whatever I wanted to achieve.
Whenever I access URL , it launches my windows app.

But, I want some customization here. I want to launch my windows app only once (or before someone access the URLs) and read values every time links gets clicked.  I searched internet like crazy and haven't found anything constructive yet.

my overall intention is to pass values to my windows app continuously with one instance opened whenever links(with my custom protocol) clicked in web application.

Comment: Did you found any solution yet?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately opening-closing is the only solution as of now because everytime I click the link it will open a new EXE